# How to remove except latest 10 record using Mongodb or mongoose lib?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using this query:

```
db.date.remove({
    _id:{ $not:{ $eq: ObjectId("570ba4f66931b8f21a8bf25f") }},
    date:{ $lt: outdated }
})
```

But it is not working properly. I don't  need to give  ids.

How to remove (delete) except latest 10  record?

Comment: You can do this in two steps. 1) Find 10th id from the end. 2) Delete everything with id less than the id you just found. This may leave you with more than 10 documents if there are inserts happening at the same time.

Comment: hi @SergioTulentsev, it is not 10 in future , it ll be dynamic value, so i need to delete except latest N record

Comment: Yes, yes, that's what it'll do.

Comment: i will try @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @Angu Check the details ans on how to delete the older records on mongo shell using shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by iterating on the sorted list of collection and you can continue for `10` or specified `N` records and then delete after it as `db.collectionName.remove({_id:ObjectId(<IteratorID>)})`

> Let us see in the details from inserting the records and then proof of concept for deleting it

Inserting 19 records in a collection `st2` (just for checking the correctness of the script) in mongo shell:

```
> for(var i =1; i<20;i++) { db.st2.insert({"a":i}) }
>
```

Some of the records look likes as:

```
> db.st2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c62e71d6ddb127f4e87dfc4"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c62e7476ddb127f4e87dfc5"), "a" : 2 }
...
...
```

Just to iterate and print the values which will be deleted [This is only for script verification purposes]

```
> var counter = 0;
> var allRecords = db.st2.find().sort({ "_id" : -1});
> var totalElements= allRecords.count()
> for(var i = 0; i<totalElements; i++) { if (i<=10) {allRecords.next();continue;} var currentRecord = allRecords.next(); print(currentRecord._id); print(currentRecord.a)};
ObjectId("5c62e7476ddb127f4e87dfcb")
8
ObjectId("5c62e7476ddb127f4e87dfca")
7
ObjectId("5c62e7476ddb127f4e87dfc9")
6
....
....
```

In the place of printing the records with id, **just delete it as `db.collectionName.remove({_id:currentRecord._id})`** check it below:

```
> var allRecords = db.st2.find().sort({ "_id" : -1});
> 
> var totalElements= allRecords.count()
> totalElements
19
> for(var i = 0; i<totalElements; i++) { if (i<=10) {allRecords.next();continue;} var currentRecord = allRecords.next(); db.st2.remove({_id:currentRecord._id});};
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
> var totalElements= allRecords.count()
> totalElements
11
>
```

Its deleted the older records and only left 11 records. just check the if condition and you can exactly left with `N` records or whatever you want.

Hope this will help you to understand it in better way, since I tried to cover it with full details so that you or someone might get benefited with these examples.